# Solve an equation containing Integral expression in short time

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, symbolic-math, symbolic-integration

I am trying to solve the following equation containing integrals using [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html):
[image]
I have tried to calculate just the integral part using the code below, but it takes a long time to generate expressions in **r**

```
from sympy import *
mean,std =0,1
Q=250
#defining Cumulative distribution function
def cdf(mean,std):
  t,x = symbols('t,x')
  cdf_eqn = (1/(std*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-(((t-mean)**2)/(2*std**2)))
  cdf = Integral(cdf_eqn, (t,-oo,x)).doit()
  return cdf
#defining Probability density function
def pdf(mean,std):
  x = symbols('x')
  pdf = (1/(std*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((( (x - mean)**2)/(2*std**2)))).doit()
  return pdf
#multiplying cdf and pdf
r,x = symbols('r,x')
equation = cdf(mean=0,std=1).subs(x,x)*pdf(mean=0,std=1).subs(x,(r + Q -x))
#getting interating equation over the limits [0,r]
final_equation = Integral(equation, (x,0,r))
#solving the equation
final_equation.doit()
```

It takes enormous amount of time to solve the equation. How can i solve the entire equation in short time using SymPy or any other package/library (scipy?)

Posting on behalf of my friend.

Comment: substitute a value for r and then evaluate to get a numerical answer instead of a symbolic answer: `final_equation.subs(r, 1).n(3)`

Comment: Hey @smichr 
do you mind taking look on this? if can help my friend on this also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278195/how-to-get-the-minimum-value-of-a-cost-function-having-two-variable-integration

Comment: I don't have anything to suggest other than what I said: substitute in a value of `r` and numerically calculation -- don't symbolically `doit` -- and you will get an answer.

Comment: @smichr that’s solved. Above is another question link I thought u can help maybe on that also

Comment: sorry...no suggestions for that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy seems to be having a hard time doing that integral. I waited for about 2 minutes on my machine and nothing popped up. Maybe it's not solvable analytically.

So I went for a numerical approach using [SciPy's root finding algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#scalar-functions).

```py
import sympy as sp
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
import time

start_time = time.time()

mean, std = 0, 1
Q = 250
p = 5
w = 2

x = sp.symbols("x")
r_symbol = sp.symbols("r")

pdf = (1 / (std * sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi))) * sp.exp(-(((x - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))
cdf = sp.erf(sp.sqrt(2) * x / 2) / 2 + 1 / 2  # pre-calculated with integrate(pdf, (x, -oo, t))


def f(r: float) -> float:
    result = sp.N(-p + (p + w * cdf.subs(x, Q)) * cdf.subs(x, r) + \
                  w * sp.Integral(cdf * pdf.subs(x, (r + Q - x)), (x, 0, r)))
    return result


r0 = 1  # initial estimate for the root
bracket = (-10, 10)  # the upper and lower bounds of where the root is
solution = root_scalar(f, x0=r0, bracket=bracket)
print(solution)  # info about the convergence
print(solution.root)  # the actual number

end_time = time.time()
print("Time taken:", end_time - start_time)
```

Which produces the following output for me:

```py
      converged: True
           flag: 'converged'
 function_calls: 14
     iterations: 13
           root: 0.5659488219328516
0.5659488219328516
Time taken: 26.701611518859863
```

The root can also be seen visually using a plot on MatPlotLib or Desmos:
[image: Plot of the root]

I assume the time taken is reasonable since it had to evaluate 14 pretty difficult integrals. However, Desmos did it in almost no time so maybe there is something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Hey thanks for help out here. It's working now. 
Can you take a look on this? if can help my friend on this also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278195/how-to-get-the-minimum-value-of-a-cost-function-having-two-variable-integration