# How to get the minimum value of a cost function, having two variable integration expression, in short time using python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I want to find the minimum value of the **cost function T**. The cost function **T** has an expression in two variables (**Q and r**). I also need to find values of **Q and r** at which the cost function **T** reaches the global minimum. (if multiple global minimum values - then all)  The bounds of Q and r are : **0 < Q < 15000 ; 0 < r < 5000**
Here are the equations

[image]

I am using [Sympy library](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html) to generate the equations. and using the minimize function of [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)  to find the minimum value. The code for the functions are:

```
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
mean, std = 291, 253
l = 7 #
m = 30
#Q = mean*(lead_time + shelf_life)
p = 5
w = 2
K = 100
c = 5
h = 0.001 #per unit per  day
x = symbols("x")
t = symbols("t")
r = symbols("r")
Q = symbols("Q")
#defining Cumulative distribution function
def cdf():
  cdf_eqn = (1/(std*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-(((t-mean)**2)/(2*std**2)))
  cdf = Integral(cdf_eqn, (t,-oo,x)).doit()
  return cdf
#defining Probability density function
def pdf():
  pdf = (1/(std*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((( (x - mean)**2)/(2*std**2)))).doit()
  return pdf
pdf = pdf()
cdf = cdf()
#getting the equation in place
G = K + c*Q + w*(Integral(cdf , (x, 0, Q)) + Integral(cdf.subs(x, (r + Q - x))*cdf , (x, 0, r)))\
     + p*(mean*l - r + Integral(cdf , (x, 0, r)))
CL = (Q - r + mean*l - Integral(cdf , (x, 0, Q)) - Integral(cdf.subs(x, (r + Q - x))*cdf , (x, 0, r)) + Integral(cdf , (x, 0, r)))/mean  
I = h*(Q + r - mean*l - Integral(cdf , (x, 0, Q)) - Integral(cdf.subs(x, (r + Q - x))*cdf , (x, 0, r)) + Integral(cdf , (x, 0, r)))/2
#TC.free_symbols
#optimising the cost function
from  scipy import optimize
def f(params):
    r, Q = params 
    TC = G/CL + I
    return TC
initial_guess = [2500., 10000.]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess, tol=1e-6 )
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

**But it throws an error as below.**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args, f0)
    699             try:
--> 700                 df = df.item()
    701             except (ValueError, AttributeError):
AttributeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute 'item'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
5 frames
<ipython-input-6-e9bb4190fef5> in <module>()
     39     return TC
     40 initial_guess = [2500., 10000.]
---> 41 result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess, tol=1e-6 )
     42 if result.success:
     43     fitted_params = result.x
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    602         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    603     elif meth == 'bfgs':
--> 604         return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    605     elif meth == 'newton-cg':
    606         return _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
   1007     else:
   1008         grad_calls, myfprime = wrap_function(fprime, args)
-> 1009     gfk = myfprime(x0)
   1010     k = 0
   1011     N = len(x0)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    325     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    326         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 327         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    328 
    329     return ncalls, function_wrapper
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in approx_fprime(xk, f, epsilon, *args)
    763 
    764     """
--> 765     return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
    766 
    767 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args, f0)
    700                 df = df.item()
    701             except (ValueError, AttributeError):
--> 702                 raise ValueError("The user-provided "
    703                                  "objective function must "
    704                                  "return a scalar value.")
ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value.
```

Additionally, with other methods, it takes a long time to run, more than 30 minutes or so and ends up throwing an error. **How can I find the global minima and also the values of Q and r in a very short time. Preferably 1-5 minutes or so.**

> Posting on behalf of my Friend

Comment: The error message does not match the code shown which gives a different error (NameError).

Comment: @OscarBenjamin sorry for that. Updated it can you give a try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note for the future: in your function `f`, if you set `r` and `Q` to something, it does not change the SymPy expressions that you use afterwards since they were already previously defined for symbolic variables.

Your work seems heavily numerical and in fact, since your answers don't need symbols, you're probably better doing non-symbolic integration. SymPy is pure Python which can be slow especially for integration while SciPy is designed to be fast. That's why I converted everything to SciPy things:

Edit: I knew that my first answer with the `r=0` convergence was fishy. After @VishalAnand's correction for the integral of the cdf starting from `-inf`, I tried running the program again. It took ~15 seconds for a single iteration of T and it was not finding a solution; probably due to a now very complex surface that now exists.

The cdf was also producing wrong values; for example, `quad(pdf, -np.inf, 50000)[0]` produced a number very close to 0 when instead it should have been close to 1. This ruined the minimization and so I tried something like `quad(pdf, -1000000, 50000)[0]` which turned out to produce similar values to `sympy.N(sympy.erf((x-mean)/(sqrt(2)*std)))/2 + 1/2` which turned out to be faster to compute.

The problem is that the SciPy minimize function could not converge but rather produced `ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH`. So I gave it a specific method to use: the Nelder-Mead. This converged. But the final values were very concerning since they were jumping between `inf` and `-1.793193606659277e+19`. Python is not known for overflow errors (at least to my knowledge) so the only possible explanation I can think of is that the function C has a root that causes T to have an asymptote at some values of r and Q.

This is far beyond me so I'll just leave my updated efforts here:

```py
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp, inf
from sympy import erf, N
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.integrate import quad

mean, std = 291, 253
l = 7
m = 30
# Q = mean*(lead_time + shelf_life)
p = 5
w = 2
K = 100
c = 5
h = 0.001  # per unit per  day


# defining Probability density function
def pdf(x):
    return (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((x - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))


# defining Cumulative distribution function
def cdf(x):
    # cdf1 = quad(pdf, -1000000, x)[0]  # slow
    # cdf2 = quad(pdf, -inf, x)[0]  # slow and produces wrong values at hugh positive x
    cdf3 = N(erf((x-mean)/(sqrt(2)*std)))/2 + 1/2
    return cdf3


# getting the equation in place
def G(r, Q):
    return K + c * Q \
           + w * (quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0] + quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]) \
           + p * (mean * l - r + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0])


def CL(r, Q):
    return (Q - r + mean * l - quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0]
            - quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]
            + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0]) / mean


def I(r, Q):
    return h * (Q + r - mean * l - quad(cdf, 0, Q)[0]
                - quad(lambda x: cdf(r + Q - x) * cdf(x), 0, r)[0]
                + quad(cdf, 0, r)[0]) / 2


def f(params):
    r, Q = params
    TC = G(r, Q)/CL(r, Q) + I(r, Q)
    return TC


initial_guess = [2343.70601496,  239.89137499]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess, bounds=[(0, 5000), (0, 15000)], method="Nelder-Mead")
# result = f(initial_guess)  # single check
print(result)
```

Resulting in the following output in ~15 seconds:

```py
 final_simplex: (array([[2343.70594323,  257.01581672],
       [2343.70594323,  257.01581672],
       [2343.70594323,  257.01581672]]), array([-1.79319361e+19, -1.79319361e+19, -1.79319361e+19]))
           fun: -1.793193606659277e+19
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 360
           nit: 155
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([2343.70594323,  257.01581672])
```

Hopefully someone more qualified can explain this. Apologies for any inconvenience or false conclusions from myself.

Comment: SymPy is not slow at integration because it is pure python but rather because it is doing symbolic integration. It can calculate integrals numerically using `Integral(...).evalf()` much faster than calculating them symbolically. The original code misses the point of using symbolic integration though which is that you can do it once (ever) and then substitute values into the analytic result rather than running a symbolic integration routine on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for help guys. My friend said it's working and helps alot.

Comment: @Maelstrom you missed specifying `-np.inf` in cumulative distribution function.i.e - `cdf = quad(cdf_eqn, -np.inf, x)[0]`